# Is it possible to get the row number of a hyperlinkfield in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have a gridfield which is being populated and in one of my cells the first there are hyperlinkfields.   I need to know if it is possible to get the rownumber of the hyperlinkfield just like it is with a buttonfield. 
Unfortunately I cannot use a buttonfield else my problem would have been solved. 
I cannot find an event associated with the hyperlinkfield and it is also not doing any postbacks if I recall the info correctly. 
If this is possible how do I achieve this ?

*as requested the edit:*

```
Protected Sub objGridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

 Dim strProID As String
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        RowNR = index
    End If
       SelectedID = RowNR
    Response.Write("<script>document.location.href = " & "('SelectedTask.aspx');</script>") 'windows.navigate doesn't work in firefox and several other browsers
End Sub
```

This was my code when i used a linkbutton.  The linkbutton from the gridview has an attribute commandname and you can use this so your event will be raised. Which I did. 
Unfortunately for the hyperlinkview cell does not have such a property. 
So I can't raise an event and see which rownumber i selected if I click on one of my with hyperlinkfilled cells.

**edit:**
So I fixed my problem with just a simple DataNavigateFormatString.
I know foolish of me to not get there sooner, but better late then never.

Why mess around with the rownumber to get the value from my cell, if I can get the value  much cleaner , quicker and without postbacks;).

Comment: Can you please put some code so that answerers can better understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: of course let me update my post.

Comment: A HyperLinkField takes the user off to another page. Not sure why/how you expect to be able run any code on your page when the user clicks it....

Comment: Because my hyperlink contains the id for the database record. 
Example ..  123849 <- this being the hyperlink and the id is being called

Comment: +1 to find answer for self trying :) keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve using "OnSelectedIndexChanging". This should help you.

Comment: I fixed it with the HyperlinkField and the DataNavigateUrlFormatString
I'll edit my post for clarity.